# Aspose cells / Closed XML insert row issue

Tags: excel, aspose, closedxml

I am using Aspose cells to open spreadsheets from dot net and insert data.  In some cases we have to insert new rows for the data, meaning stuff below the insertion point gets pushed down.  Trouble is, anything referencing cells in those rows (eg a named range) breaks when you try and open the workbook.  Does anyone know if there is a way to make Aspose "automatically" update all cell references when a row is inserted via code?  I have a also tried using closed xml, same issue.  Aspose is normally very robust so I am surprised it cannot handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to use the specific overload, i.e., Cells.InsertRows(int rowIndex, int totalRows,bool updateReference). When you put "true" for the last Boolean parameter, it would make sure that all references in other worksheets will be updated accordingly.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks Amjad, I will try that method